# PHP return true in a function after first word is found

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string, search

I have an array filled with words:

```
$words = array("word", "word2", "apple", "cake");
```

Then I want to use this array in a function that will check to see if a word exists in a string ($text) like so...

```
function find_word($text) {
    $words = array("word", "word2", "apple", "cake");
}
```

...but I want the function to stop checking if the words exist and return **true** after the FIRST occurrence of one of the words in the array, is in the string ($text). (So the function won't have to check every single word against the string.) If the word isn't found, then I want it to return false.

I've tried searching some methods up, and the only things that I was able to find were methods that used `preg_match`, but they checked every single word in the array against the string, which I think would slow the script down.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

**NOTE:** I want this function to return true even if one of the words in the array, is in the word. For example: `blahAPPLErandom` should return true, because `apple` is in there.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($words); $i++)
    if (stripos($text, $words[$i]) !== false)
        return true;
```

Comment: I believe that should be `stripos` for case-insensitve, as per OP's `blahAPPLErandom` - `APPLE` and `apple` will not be treated the same.

Answer (score 0):

What about using stristr PHP function?

```
function find_word($text) {
    $words = array("word", "word2", "apple", "cake");
    foreach ($words as $w) {
        if (stristr($text, $w)) return True;
    }
    return False;
}
```